# How can I multiply elements in one list while providing a range in another

Tags: python, list

I have two lists that I will later use do determine on how many pages of a document I'm looking at. The first list (l_name) contains the name of the document. The second list (l_depth) contains the number of pages I will look at, always starting from the first one.

The original lists look like this:

```
l_name = ['Doc_1', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_3']
l_depth = [1, 3, 2]
```

As I want to use a for loop to indicate each page I will be looking at

```
for d,p in zip(l_doc, l_page):
  open doc(d) on page(p)
  do stuff
```

I need the new lists to look like this:

```
l_doc = ['Doc_1', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_3', 'Doc_3']
l_page = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

How can I multiply the names (l_name --> l_doc) based on the required depth and provide the range (l_depth --> l_page) also based on the depth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
l_name = ['Doc_1', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_3']
l_depth = [1, 3, 2]
l_doc = []
for i,j in zip(l_name, l_depth):
    l_doc += [i]*j
# ['Doc_1', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_3', 'Doc_3']

l_page = [k for _,j in zip(l_name, l_depth) for k in range(1,j+1)]
# [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get your list with comprehension:

```
[k for i, j in zip(l_name, l_depth) for k in [i]*j]
```

Comment: `[(k,j) for i, j in zip(l_name, l_depth) for k in [i]*j]`

Comment: `l_doc, l_page = zip(*[(k,j) for i, j in zip(l_name, l_depth) for k in [i]*j])`

Comment: @olivecoder your `l_page` would be `(1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2)`

Comment: oh, yeah. I saw that but I didnt pay enough attention to the question hence I thought that was the expected result

Comment: `[(k,p+1) for i, j in zip(l_name, l_depth) for p,k in enumerate([i]*j)]`

Answer (score 3):

With builtin `zip` and `itertools.chain.from_iterable` functions:

```
from itertools import chain

l_name = ['Doc_1', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_3']
l_depth = [1, 3, 2]

result = list(chain.from_iterable([n]*d for n, d in zip(l_name, l_depth)))
print(result)
```

The output:

```
['Doc_1', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_3', 'Doc_3']
```

Answer (score 2):

For the page list you can do the same as zippa suggested:

```
[k+1 for i, j in zip(l_name, l_depth) for k in range(j)]
```

output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

We have all good answers already, but hey I was doing it already so here you go:

```
l_name = ['Doc_1', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_3']
l_depth = [1, 3, 2]
l_result = []
index = 0

for depth in l_depth:
  for times in range(depth):
    l_result.append(l_name[index])
  index +=1

print(l_result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @zipa answer:

```
l_doc_page =  [(k,p+1) for i, j in zip(l_name, l_depth) for p,k in enumerate([i]*j)]
```

That would give you:

```
[('Doc_1', 1), ('Doc_2', 1), ('Doc_2', 2), ('Doc_2', 3), ('Doc_3', 1), ('Doc_3', 2)]
```

You can use `l_doc_page` directly if you were planning to zip the lists together when iterating:

```
for doc, page in l_doc_page: do_sth(doc, page)
```

or you can unzip and unpack the lists:

```
l_doc, l_page = zip(*l_doc_page)
```

and then you get the result required by the question:

```
>>> l_doc, l_page=zip(*((k,p+1) for i, j in zip(l_name, l_depth) for p,k in enumerate([i]*j)))
>>> l_doc
('Doc_1', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_3', 'Doc_3')
>>> l_page
(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) based one  using [`repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
from itertools import repeat

l_name = ['Doc_1', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_3']
l_depth = iter([1, 3, 2])

[i for i in l_name for j in repeat(i, next(l_depth))]
# ['Doc_1', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_3', 'Doc_3']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l_name = ['Doc_1', 'Doc_2', 'Doc_3']
l_depth = [1, 3, 2]

l_doc = []
l_page = []

for i, j in zip(l_name, l_depth):
    l_doc += [i] * j
    l_page += range(1, j + 1)

print(l_doc)
print(l_page)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ret = sum([[ (name, i) for i in  range(1, depth + 1)] for name, depth in zip(l_name, l_depth)], [])
l_doc, l_page = zip(*ret)
```